# No Android Project Option in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt

I'm using Windows 7 64-bit with Eclipse Classic Juno installed.
I have already installed the ATD plugin and Android SDK.
So here's the problem:
When i go NEW -> Project -> Others
and choosing the Android folder, all i see is Android Activity, Android Application Project, Android Test Project...etc. There's NO "Android Project" in it.

I've tried choosing the "Android Application Project" but after clicking finish, the create project windows wont close but a new project is created as shown in the package explorer.
When i click in, the source folder is empty. Should't there be something there?

is there anything i've done wrong? 
Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you set the path of the Android development kit in Window -> Preferences ?

Comment: Yes I have everything installed...i can't create an activity, everytime i click finish, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, I've never encountered this before, there is obviously something wrong with the android ADT plugin. Or your eclipse distribution. the only advice I can give you is to try on a virgin eclipse distribution.

Alternatively you can create your project in the command line using this tutorial. http://incise.org/android-development-on-the-command-line.html and then import it into eclipse. (not very pretty though).

You can also uninstall the android ADT plugin.
Click Help > Install new software.
Select the link that says What is already installed?
It will open up The installation details dialog, you can then uninstall all the android plugins and re-install.

Hope it helps

Comment: I have already tried re-installing my eclipse(juno) several times, i've also tried eclipse for java developer and eclipse classic. The problem still persists. I've already installed a JDK and SDK so I don't think that is causing the problem. :(

Comment: Okay, so i've had a go at it, it seems like they've modified the android adt plugin quite a bit, but I'm still able to create new Projects as well as activities. when you're creating the projec there is a checkbox option to create a new activity. if you don't check that box you won't have an activity after the project is created.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this same annoying problem here. Spent 3 hours attempting everything. Unninstalling and installing all possible and impossible plugins... And when I was close to lost all hope, it misteriously worked!!! \o/

What did I do? Nothing unusual. The correct question is: what didn't I do...

Let's go with my further investigations: when I was creating a new app using that new icon creation tool and **using TEXT** instead of clipart or image nothing worked. BUT, when I used a clipart, BINGO, evrything worked gracefully as it was supposed to and as it worked before many times.

Simple as that: DON'T CREATE A ICON USING A TEXT. It's bugged. I checked here. Deleted app, tried to create again with text icon: bad. Tried again with clipart: good!

And that's it! hope my answer was of any help... ;]